# How to check for last item when looping through a structure in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I want to loop over a structure and output something for all items except the last one. For arrays this can easily be done by checking whether the current index is the last one, though how to do it for structures?

Example code:

```
<cfscript>
myStruct = {
  item1 = "foo",
  item2 = "bar",
  item3 = "baz"
};
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
<cfloop collection="#myStruct#" item="item">
  #myStruct[item]#
  <!--- Here should be the conditional output --->
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increment your own "index" as you loop:

```
<cfscript>
myStruct = {
  item1 = "foo",
  item2 = "bar",
  item3 = "baz"
};
totalItems = StructCount( myStruct );
thisItemNumber = 1;
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
<cfloop collection="#myStruct#" item="item">
  #myStruct[item]#
  <cfset thisIsNotTheLastItem = ( thisItemNumber LT totalItems )>
    <cfif thisIsNotTheLastItem>
        is not the last item<br/>
    </cfif>
    <cfset thisItemNumber++>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

EDIT: Here's an alternative using an array

```
<cfscript>
myStruct = {
  item1 = "foo",
  item2 = "bar",
  item3 = "baz"
};
totalItems = StructCount( myStruct );
keys = StructKeyArray( myStruct );
lastItem = myStruct[ keys[ totalItems ] ];
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#keys#" item="key">
    #myStruct[ key ]#
    <cfif myStruct[ key ] IS NOT lastItem>
        is not the last item<br/>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I ended up with a code very similar to this one, so thank you for that! I'm just wondering if there's a nicer solution for that similar to an array loop.

Comment: Have added an alternative which uses an array loop.

Comment: @SebastianZartner Structs do not maintain the insertion order so, you might want to use `LinkedHashMap` for always ignoring the last inserted item. Check [this](https://www.trycf.com/gist/06fc80a23f383a17001da8fd3f73dfa5/acf11?theme=monokai) gist.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a simple solution.

```
<cfscript>
    myStruct = {
      item1 = "foo",
      item2 = "bar",
      item3 = "baz"
   };
</cfscript>
<cfset KeyListArray = ListToArray(StructKeyList(myStruct))>
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#(ArrayLen(KeyListArray)-1)#" index="i"> 
       #myStruct[i]#
      <!--- Here should be the conditional output --->
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Actually I voted for this, but in fact it doesn't do what the OP seems to be asking for. The code suggests they want to output the value of **all** items and then conditionally something else **unless** it's the last item.

Comment: In that case,  to="#ArrayLen(KeyListArray)#" , it will work right?

Comment: No, that's just a long way of looping over the entire struct. Surely you need some conditional code inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, in fact I want to output a separator between the items, so the solution above doesn't cover this.

Comment: Note that instead of `ListToArray(StructKeyList(myStruct))` you could simply use [`StructKeyArray(myStruct)`](https://cfdocs.org/structkeyarray).